# How to use cookie in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, httpcookie

I cant understand how to use cookies in ZF2? Can some one advise some links with set and get cookie?

Comment: http://de.php.net/manual/de/features.cookies.php Nothing Zend Specific here... Going with how many entry level questions you got, you might be advised to learn basic OOP PHP5 programming - outside of ZF :S

Comment: i know how to use cookie outside ZF, but how it works in Zf2?

Comment: so i find out how it works how to close a question?

Comment: You should write down how it works as an answer, for other people who may look for the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use the `rememberMe()` method on the `SessionManager` to set a cookie

See [SessionManager Code](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Session/SessionManager.php) on line 260

there also is `forgetMe()` to remove the cookie

additionally you can configure the defaults for your session manager like this:

**Module.php**

```
public function onBootstrap(\Zend\EventManager\EventInterface $e)

    $config = $e->getApplication()
        ->getServiceManager();
        ->get('Configuration');

    $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
    $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);
    $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig, null, null);
    Session::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
}
```

**module.config.php**

```
return array(
    'session' => array(
        'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
        'use_cookies' => true,
        'cookie_httponly' => true,
    ),
);
```

See [this class](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Session/Config/SessionConfig.php) for a complete list of configuration options: