# session doesnt clear in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, zend-framework2

I wanted to know why does my session not clear in ZF2. I am creating an Authenticate session and setting remember me time to 10 secs. But i can still see my session variables upon var_dump($_SESSION) after 10 secs. Why does the session variables are visible after 10 secs on the view page. Thanks

Comment: Its Becuase ZF2 has its own criteria of handling Sessions, ZF donot typically use PHP based Sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the [`SessionConfig`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.session.config.html)-Section of the Documentation.

The settings can be translated into your application/module-config in the following manner:

```
return array(
    'session' => array(
        'remember_me_seconds' => 10
    )
);
```

Then you'll need to let the [`SessionManager`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.session.manager.html) know about the `SessionConfig`. For this, please see the answer provided here: [How to Bootstrap Sessions in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774809/how-to-bootstrap-sessions-in-zend-framework-2)

Comment: you should accept this answer if it is the correct one