# ZF2 Dafault Database Session Storage

Tags: database, session, zend-framework2

I am busy writing a DB Session module so I can quickly install it between multiple applications.  The module will be loaded from the autoloader as the first module to be started.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to change the default session container / session handler to be the default session handler for all modules and it should also be database hosted sessions.  I've been strugling with zf2 session handler for quite a while now and the errors in the logs make 0 sense.  So here what I have so far.  A basic module with Module.php containing...

namespace DBSession;

```
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;

class Module {

    public function onBootstrap($e) {
        $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
        $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Config');
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $controller->config = $config;
        new \DBSession\Storage\DBStorage();
    }

    public function getConfig() {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

And the actual class that initiates the DB session handler.

```
namespace DBSession\Storage;

use Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGateway;
use Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGatewayOptions;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;
use Zend\Session\Container;

class DBStorage {

    public function __construct() {
        $dbAdapter = new Adapter(array(
                    'driver' => 'Mysqli',
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'dbname' => 'zf2_session',
                    'username' => 'zf2',
                    'password' => 'testme',
                    'options' => array(
                        'buffer_results' => true,
                    ),
                ));

        $tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('session', $dbAdapter);


        $gwOpts = new DbTableGatewayOptions();
        $gwOpts->setDataColumn('data');
        $gwOpts->setIdColumn('id');
        $gwOpts->setLifetimeColumn('lifetime');
        $gwOpts->setModifiedColumn('modified');
        $gwOpts->setNameColumn('name');


        $saveHandler = new DbTableGateway($tableGateway, $gwOpts);
        $sessionManager = new SessionManager();
        $sessionManager->setSaveHandler($saveHandler);
        return Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
    }

}
```

When trying to create a session I see the following in the logs which I have 0 clue how to fix.  This is starting to make me hate magic...

```
[29-Nov-2012 20:47:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\Db\Sql\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Not a valid magic property for this object' in /document_root/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Select.php:764
Stack trace:
#0 /document_root/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Select.php(163): Zend\Db\Sql\Select->__get('tableReadOnly')
#1 /document_root/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Select.php(146): Zend\Db\Sql\Select->from('session')
#2 /document_root/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Sql.php(65): Zend\Db\Sql\Select->__construct('session')
#3 /document_root/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php(191): Zend\Db\Sql\Sql->select()
#4 /document_root/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Session/SaveHandler/DbTableGateway.php(134): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select(Array)
#5 [internal function]: Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGateway->write(' in /document_root/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Select.php on line 764
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code for your `$dbTableGateway` you must be trying to access the property **tableReadOnly**.. maybe like `$sql->tableReadOnly` or `$select->tableReadOnly` which does not exist, therefore it invokes the `__get()` magic method. If you look at the source for that, you will see that it uses a `switch` on the property name which defaults to throwing an exception.  (Zend/Db/Sql/Select.php line 764)

Comment: The thing about the **RIDICULOUS** amount of abstraction in ZF2 is that it's much harder to track down bugs or errors.  Also it seems their exception messages are even more ambiguous than before as well.  It's hard for me (or anyone else for that matter) to tell you exactly where your bug is because it's not in any of the code you posted per se.

Comment: @mmmshuddup Thats literally the only code there is I'm not setting anything else anywhere else which makes this so frustrating.

Comment: Yeah it's hard in ZF2.  Sorry I couldn't help more..  At this point you could do a step-into-style debug mode (if using eclipse or any professional grade IDE) using a breakpoint somewhere in that part of your code to see what's really going on.  That's the best advice I can give at this point.

Comment: Or try adding `die('here');` statements within your `DbStorage::__construct()` method to see which tablegateway is throwing the error.  etc etc

Comment: For now I created a a bug against zf2 as I traced out the issue to be in the DB Gateway class, so hopefully they will come back and either accept it is a bug or give some clue as to how to do it properly. For reference the bug is here: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3108

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all of the fixes that have recently gone into ZF2 my original solution is now working without modification however, I have added a new composer module for anyone that wants to use it, it reduces the need to do it all manually.

Installation details are in the readme file on: https://github.com/Nitecon/DBSessionStorage

Enjoy and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 5):

**update :**

zend framework >= 2.2, this issue is no more .

**Old answer :**

I have faced same issue on storing session into database , I have written  initDbSession function inside basic module class `\module\Application\Module.php`

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        // session start from here
        $this->initDbSession( $e );

    }


    /** 
     * Store session into database
     * 
     * @param type $e
     */
    private function initDbSession( MvcEvent $e )
    {
        // grab the config array
        $serviceManager     = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $config             = $serviceManager->get('config');

        $dbAdapter          = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

        /* some how this not works for me 
        $sessionOptions = new \Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGatewayOptions( null );

        $sessionTableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('session', $dbAdapter);
        $saveHandler = new \Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGateway($sessionTableGateway, $sessionOptions);

        */

        /* I written my own save handler , I am using mysql as database */
        $saveHandler   = new \My\Session\SaveHandler\Mysql( $config['db'] );

        $sessionConfig = new \Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig();
        $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);

        // pass the saveHandler to the sessionManager and start the session
        $sessionManager = new \Zend\Session\SessionManager( $sessionConfig , NULL, $saveHandler );
        $sessionManager->start();

        \Zend\Session\Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);

    }    

    // other function goes here ...
```

Here my config file , which is located in `\config\autoload\global.php`

```
return array(        
        'db' => array(
            'driver'         => 'Pdo',
            'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2;host=localhost',
            'driver_options' => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'',
                'buffer_results' => true
            ),
            'username'       => 'root',
            'password'       => '',
            'host'           => 'localhost',
            'dbname'         => 'zf2',
        ),         
        'session' => array(
              'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
              'use_cookies'       => true,
              'cookie_httponly'   => true,
              'cookie_lifetime'   => 2419200,
              'gc_maxlifetime'    => 2419200,

        ),
        'service_manager' => array(
            'factories' => array(                
                'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory'
            )
        )
);
```

Mysql Table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `session` (
`id` CHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`modified` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`lifetime` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`data` TEXT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Custom Mysql save handler class is given below . I have written this class, because  new `Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGateway`
not working on my server . My custom Mysql session save handler class written on `\library\My\Session\SaveHandler\Mysql.php`

```
<?php

namespace My\Session\SaveHandler;

use Zend\Session\SaveHandler\SaveHandlerInterface;

/**
 * Description of Mysql
 *
 * @author rab
 */
class Mysql  implements SaveHandlerInterface 
{

    /**
     * Session Save Path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $sessionSavePath;

    /**
     * Session Name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $sessionName;

    /**
     * Lifetime
     * @var int
     */
    protected $lifetime;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     */
    public function __construct( $dbConfig )
    {

        $this->dbconn  = mysql_connect(
            $dbConfig['host'],
            $dbConfig['username'], 
            $dbConfig['password']
        );

        if ( $this->dbconn ) {
            return mysql_select_db($dbConfig['dbname'], $this->dbconn);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Open the session
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function open( $savePath, $name )
    {
        $this->sessionSavePath = $savePath;
        $this->sessionName     = $name;
        $this->lifetime        = ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');

        return true;

    }


    /**
     * Close the session
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function close() 
    {

        return mysql_close($this->dbconn);
    }


    /**
     * Read the session
     * 
     * @param int session id
     * @return string string of the sessoin
     */
    public function read($id) 
    {

            $id     = mysql_real_escape_string($id);

            $sql    = "SELECT `data` FROM `session` " .
                      "WHERE id = '$id'";

            if ( $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->dbconn)) {
                if ( mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
                    $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    return $record['data'];
                }
            }

            return '';
    }


    /**
     * Write the session
     * 
     * @param int session id
     * @param string data of the session
     */
    public function write($id, $data ) 
    {

            $data   = (string) $data ;

            $dbdata = array(
                'modified' => time(),
                'data'     => mysql_real_escape_string( $data  ) ,
            );

            $selectSql = "SELECT * FROM session 
                          WHERE id = '$id' AND name = '{$this->sessionName}' ";

            $rs          = mysql_query( $selectSql, $this->dbconn );

            if ( $rs = mysql_query( $selectSql , $this->dbconn)) {
                if ( mysql_num_rows($rs) ) {

                    $updateSql = "UPDATE `session` SET 
                           `modified`= '".$dbdata['modified'] . "' ,
                           `data`= '".$dbdata['data']. "' 
                            WHERE id= '$id' AND name = '{$this->sessionName}' ";


                    mysql_query( $updateSql ,  $this->dbconn );
                    return true;

                }
            }


            $dbdata['lifetime']  = $this->lifetime;
            $dbdata['id']        = $id;
            $dbdata['name']      = $this->sessionName;

            $insertSql =  "INSERT INTO session (". implode(',' , array_keys($dbdata)) .")"
                           ."VALUES ('" . implode("','" , array_values( $dbdata )). "')";

            return mysql_query( $insertSql, $this->dbconn);

    }


    /**
     * Destoroy the session
     * 
     * @param int session id
     * @return bool
     */
    public function destroy($id) 
    {

            $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM `session` WHERE `id` = '%s'", $id);
            return mysql_query($sql, $this->dbconn);
    }


    /**
     * Garbage Collector
     * 
     * @param int life time (sec.)
     * @return bool
     */
    public function gc( $maxlifetime ) 
    {

            $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM `session` WHERE `modified` < '%s'",
                    mysql_real_escape_string(time() - $maxlifetime)
            );

            return mysql_query($sql, $this->dbconn);
    }

}
```

Which saves my session values into db table . For more information you can check http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: thank you for this I will test it shortly, however based on the question itself I can't take a workaround as an answer as I'm looking for the actual Zend implementation method.  However I will test your solution shortly and will definitely upvote if it works!

Comment: so far this solution of yours seems to be working great.  I'm making a few modifications in order to hydrate the sql etc but it seems to be working out well...  I still have not heard anything from ZF2 side so if nothing shows up by the end of this week then I'll be sure to give you the answer

Comment: may be its a bug in zf2 '\Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTableGateway'

Comment: It definitely is, I traced out the issue and submitted a bug against their issue tracker a few days ago.

Here is the link: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3108

Comment: Comment on https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3108 indicates that it is an issue and a pull request has already been completed fixing the issue: Below was copied from mwillbanks's comment
This is the same issue as: #2628

Overall; this is happening due to SessionManager::writeClose not being called prior to the end of the response.

A temporary fix for you, after creating the session manager, then do:

register_shutdown_function(array($sessionManager, 'writeClose'));
This should solve your issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another similar solution: 
[How to use cookie in Zend Framework 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707532/ho-to-use-cookie-in-zend-framework-2)

make sure you change this line:

```
Session::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
```

With this one:

```
Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
```

Using:

```
use Zend\Session\Container;
```